# How do I use $_FILES in a function?

Tags: php

I have some code that is supposed to upload a file and move it to the correct folder:

```
$check = getimagesize($files['image']['tmp_name']);
    if($check !== false)
    {
      $dir = "/var/www/public_html/images/";
      $file = $dir.basename($files['image']['name']);
      if(file_exists($file)) 
      {
        $img = "https://example.com/images/".basename($files['image']['name']);
      }
      else
      {
        move_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name'], $file);
        $img = "https://example.com/images/".basename($files['image']['name']);
      }
    }
```

The issue is that this code is in a function (and a different file), so I cannot directly use `$_FILES`. In my other file, where the post occurs, I have this:

```
Images::editImage($post, $_FILES)
```

It works for post, but not for files. Is there any way to carry `$_FILES` across files?

Comment: Those `$files` should most likely be `$_FILES`.

Comment: `$files` should be `$_FILES`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Beat me to it. And you're up late. ;)

Comment: @JohnConde I was just heading off to lah-lah land now. OP is also using a URL instead of a server path ;-) might be an issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ignore the `$img` as it has nothing to do with the file upload itself. It is a URL that the database needs.

Comment: _“The issue is that this code is in a function (and a different file), so I cannot directly use $_FILES”_ – that’s nonsense; $_FILES is part of the so-called [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: So I was 50% right and 50% wrong ;-) *or, was I?*

Comment: So for my function would it just be `static function editImage($post, $_FILES)`

Comment: @JohnConde I did this and no luck. Do I have to use a relative path? Will an absolute path work?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it still does not work. I'm working with two different files here. When the file is posted, it goes to that same page (with `if(isset$_POST['submit'])`) that then calls a function in another file.

Comment: You don’t need to pass `$_FILES` into your function as a parameter, you can just access `$_FILES` _directly_ inside your function.

Comment: @CBroe I tried and it does not work.

Comment: First check you have this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` and then check with `var_dump($_FILES)` and `$_FILES` is a global variable and you can directly use it in your functions instead of passing as an argument

Comment: @tzafar It was in the form! `enctype="multipart/form-data"` fixed it.

Comment: @ChrisRockGM glad to hear you have fixed the issue

Comment: @ChrisRockGM I had a sneaking suspicion about the enctype, and wanted to ask if you had it in your form to start with, and took it for granted that you did. Funny how the instincts work ;-) Glad it got resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

> *The issue is that this code is in a function (and a different file),*
>   *so I cannot directly use $_FILES.*

is false. `$_FILES` as a superglobal variable can be used everywhere in a script, class method, function, ...

So, if "*... not working*" is occurring, the problem might either be that it is not populated due to plainly missing an uploaded file, or access to it's array elements is wrong.

Comment: This was part of my issue, the latter part was that I forgot to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form.